# Edits by other users to clarify the question to keep it from being closed

Tags: discussion, specific-question, suggested-edits

[Specific edit in question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/24335)

How should we handle edits like this one?

I assumed that the user that is suggesting the edit is actually the user that posted the question and has now created themselves a real user rather than a generic user1234 user.  I don't know if that is true or not though.

Comment: What's the harm in someone suggesting an edit that makes an off topic question on topic? (Putting aside that it turned out to be OP)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the edit looks legitimate (it still makes sense with the question), it should be okay to accept the edit anyway.  That way, if it turns out that the edit was *not* done by the same user, it can easily be rolled back by a moderator.  But if it's still rejected, then the OP will have to make the edit with the *original account* to ensure that it's done.

It turns out that the users are the same, so I've requested an account merge.  As such, do not be alarmed that the questions shows a suggested edit from the OP; I assume that's by-design.